# Scala: accessing shadowed parameter/variable

Tags: scala

I have the following code, and 2 situations
Inside the

1. `if` in the method `hideVariableFromOuterBlock` I am declaring a
   variable `k` which shadows the one defined in the outer
   block.
2. inside the second method `hideParameterName` I am declaring a variable `k` which shadows the parameter with the same name.

```scala
object Test extends App {
  def hideVariableFromOuterBlock() = {
    var k = 2457
    if (k % 2 != 0) {
      var k = 47
      println(k) // this prints 47
      //println(outer k)
    }
    println(k) // - this prints 2457 as expected
  }

  def hideParameterName(k: Int) = {
    var k = 47
    println(k) // this prints 47
    //println(parameter k)
  }

  hideVariableFromOuterBlock()
  hideParameterName(2457)
}
```

Is there any way in the blocks where I have shadowed the variable or parameter `k` to access the shadowed value (the variable from the outer block)?

I am aware that this is not a good practice, and I will never do that. I am asking the question for educational purposes.

I did a bit of research and failed to find a clear explanation. I could clearly find/see that shadowing occurs, but found no clear explanation that the variable from the outer block can't be accessed anymore.

I am newbie in Scala.

Comment: I would first say `var` is not the most interesting in idiomatic Scala.

Comment: I agree with you, as far as I studied, at least the `_` is more interesting than `var` and other things too.

Comment: I mean that a more idiomatic solution would tend to avoid mutable values.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031343/469220) answer talks about why shadowing is allowed in the first place.

As for a way to access the shadowed value, the simplest thing to do as far as I know is to rename the inner variable and the problem goes away. I suppose, for the sake of the exercise, if you really don't want to rename anything, you could assign the outer variable to a new one with a different name.

```
var k = 2457
val outer_k = k
if (k % 2 != 0) {
  var k = 47
  println(k) // this prints 47
  println(outer_k)
}
```

Comment: The answer you mentioned, although very strong, expresses a personal opinion on why shadowing is allowed.
Also, it is pretty obvious how to fix the code by copying the value into another variable/constant.