# Is this instance of apply failure?

Tags: scala

Scala version = 2.10.6
Shouldn't this code fail because of re-used identifier?

```
object ScalaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val Trouble = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(Trouble(2))
  }
}

object Trouble {
  def apply(i: Int) = println("in trouble")
}
```

Prints:

```
3
```

Comment: You can't define identifier with the same name in the same scope. In your case, you define identifier with the same name in two different scopes, which is legal. Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031106/why-does-scala-support-shadow-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html) states:

> A binding has a *scope* in which the entity defined by a single name can
>   be accessed using a simple name. Scopes are nested. A binding in some
>   inner scope *shadows* bindings of lower precedence in the same scope as
>   well as bindings of the same or lower precedence in outer scopes.

You have one scope for `Trouble` defined inside the *method*, and another for an object defined inside the *package*. Since each of these scopes is independent, there are no name collisions.

If you moved the definition of your `Trouble` object into the *method* scope:

```
object ScalaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    object Trouble {
      def apply(i: Int) = println("in trouble")
    }

    val Trouble = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(Trouble(2))
  }
}
```

Then the compiler would complain:

```
Error:(9, 9) Trouble is already defined as object Trouble
    val Trouble = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
        ^
```

Note that it is discuraged to use pascal case for variable names. One can quickly get confused as types that have an `unapply` method may also be used for type decomposition, for example:

```
object Trouble {
  def unapply(ints: Array[Int]): Option[Int] = Some(ints(0))
  def apply(i: Int) = println("in trouble")
}
```

Now when you run:

```
object ScalaTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val Trouble() = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(Trouble(2))
  }
}
```

The results are completely different:

```
in trouble
()
```